# Can a 12 speed Shimano micro spline cassette be used with SRAM Eagle 12 speed components?

Tags: shimano, drivetrain, sram, shifting

Is it possible to use a Shimano 12 speed micro spline cassette with a SRAM Eagle 12 speed chainring, derailleur, and possibly chain? Or are there any incompatibilities, such as a Shimano chain also needing to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SRAM and Shimano 12 speed are cross compatible. The pull ratio is slightly off (offhand I believe it’s 1.76 for SRAM vs 1.7 for Shimano), but it seems to work fine in the real world.

To get the nice Shimano “Hyperglide+” shifting, you would need both a Shimano cassette and chain. It would shift without it, just not as well.

Of course, you cannot use SRAM XD cassettes on a Shimano MicroSpline freehub body or vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Too bad these comments are 2years old, but I’ve found out the hard way that there are no microspline cassettes that will work with my AXS electronic derailleur. I put a MS 125 10-52T cassette with microspline on my Mavic rear wheel using the AXS electronic derailleur and the chain hung up on adjacent cogs as I pedaled. The spacing of the cogs on the MS 125 cassette are less than the spacing on the Sram Eagle 1275 cassette. Also, the microspline free hub on the Mavic hub cannot be converted to a X-D freehub. End result: I have a 27.5” rear wheel that is unusable.